# aws ec2 caching (always returns 304)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, apache2

I have created a fresh EC2 instance, installed Apache2 and pointed my domain (hamidlab.com) to ip of this instance. When I browse my domain it shows default apache/ubuntu page, then I stopped apache2 service and try to access (hamidlab.com) it still shows apache/ubuntu default page, now when I try to access 1.hamidlab.com it says

### **Could Not Connect**

---

**Description: Could not connect to the requested server host.**

---

and returns Header Status Code: **502 Connection refused**

I tried with nginx server, still same caching issue.

Do AWS have any caching set ?
I am not using any other service than ec2.

Comment: Aws does not have any caching set. Check for any html files present which may have been called. Once you change the ip, wait for some time to propagate the changes.

Comment: This is a fresh EC2 and fresh installed Apache web server, their is no html File I have created or modified. 
When I change domain the "502 header" is show, who is sending this 502 header?
I think their is some timeout for the cached (here apache default page), now I am not seeing that default page.

Apache may be setting cache header, but when Apache is stopped how browser is receiving 502 header?